# MongoDB has suddently shut down with "code 100" after months of running

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have an ubuntu server running MongoDB and it has successfully been running for over a year now without any problems. Today suddenly it crashed throwing me a code 100.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-6-171:~/project$ mongod
2021-10-21T17:14:23.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=868751 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-26-6-171
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.8
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 8e540c0b6db93ce994cc548f000900bdc740f80a
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-10-21T17:14:23.215+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2021-10-21T17:14:23.220+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2021-10-21T17:14:23.220+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2021-10-21T17:14:23.220+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Why is it out of nowhere while running smoothly suddenly face this error? No changes has been made or anything. It hasn't been touched. It just stopped working out of the blue...

And has I lost the database?

How do I get it up and running again? And without data loss.

**EDIT FOR SOLUTION**

I made the directory `/data/db` and moved the database files to this destination. Why it has worked for over a year and then suddenly do this, is still unknown. But fixed with this solution.

Comment: how much RAM/disk space is available? Also, what are the permissions on the /var/lib/mongodb file?

Comment: also does the directory exist? /data/db if so what are the permissions on it?

Comment: Ram: 242 used out of 977; available 572 || 
Disk: 6.7G used out of 39G; available 33G || 
/var/lib/mongodb is not a file but a folder. The permission is: drwxr-xr-x

Comment: make sure like above you have the /data/db

Comment: Was probably started with a different/custom configurations then than now. You just started it with default config and it looked for the data files in the default spot which is `/data/db` and didn't find it. Guessing from what you wrote as the solution, of course.

Comment: It was running on the server, and then suddenly didn't work. No reboot of server or anything. But the most important is, that it is working now :) Thanks for the comments.